# Exchange Server 2010: move mailboxes from recoveded and mounted edb to user’s mailbox

Tags: exchange, disaster-recovery, exchange-2010

One of our exchange servers crashed, and I am trying to recover the mailboxes.

We had 1 exchange 2003 server named "apex" and 1 exchange 2010 server named "2008Enterprise.

the exchange 2010 server named "2008Enterprise" crashed.

I created a new exchange 2010 server named "Providence".

I ran the command on Providence:

New-MailboxDatabase -Recovery -Name JBCMail -Server Providence -EdbFilePath "c:\data\Exchange\Mailbox\Mailbox Database 0579285147\Mailbox Database 0579285147.edb" -LogFolderPath "c:\data\Exchange\Mailbox\Mailbox Database 0579285147"

this command executed and finished without error

I then ran the command:

eseutil /p E00

this command was executed from the below directory: c:\data\Exchange\Mailbox\Mailbox Database 0579285147

I then mounted the JBCMail with the mount command note: I do not have my full typed command.

Inside my Exchange Management Console (EMC) I can view the new mailbox database named JBCMail. The JBCMail database is show as mounted on the exchange server named Providence.

I can see the crashed Exchange server named 2008Exchange. In the EMC the crashed exchange server states the Copy Status under ServerConfiguration->Mailbox is ServiceDown.

From here I need to recover three mailboxes

The mail boxes are on the apex server.

How do I move the mailboxs from apex to Providence?
How do I restore the mailboxes from JBCmail mounted database to the user's mailbox?

I do not fully understand how to use the Restore-Mailbox command because when I use this command it tries to restore the mailbox to the dead apex server.

Restore-Mailbox -ID 'Jason Young' -RecoveryDatabase JBCMail

Comment: You lose me when you say "The mail boxes are on the apex server" after having already said "the exchange 2010 server named "2008Enterprise" crashed." Are you saying that you've already created new mailboxes (on the server "apex") for the users who had mailboxes on the "2008enterprise" server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new mailboxes for the users. Once you have new mailboxes for them, the [`Restore-Mailbox`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/restore-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) command will use that mailbox instead of trying (and failing) to find the old mailbox.